# Rerun current Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkins job A that triggers Jenkins job B.

I want to do some stuff (deploy to env1), and at last I want Jenkins job B to rerun itself when some conditions is OK and deploy to env2 and rerun again and deploy to env3. My problem is that after I approve to continue, nothing happens. I want the job to automatic trigger itself after approval.

I also want the parameters to be the same as the first run, but I want to update som values in my environment.

This is what I've tried:

```
stage('Continue deploy?') {
    when {
        branch 'develop' }
    }
    steps {
        input message: "Continue deploy to env2?"
        script {
            if (currentBuild.result) {
                if (env.ENVIRONMENT == 'env1') {
                    env.ENVIRONMENT = 'env2'
                } else input message: "Continue deploy to env3?"
                env.ENVIRONMENT = '3'

                currentBuild.restart()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to trigger the JOb B 3 times one after another with manual approval?

Following psudo is for is Job A

```
def envList = ['env1', 'env2', 'env']

for(int i=0; i < envList.size(); i++) {
  def b = build job: "JobB", wait: true, parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'envName', value: envList[i]]]
  if (b.result == 'SUCCESS') {
      input message: "Continue deploy to next environment?"
  }
}
```